# Best way to get distance between 2 lat long using angularjs in ng-repeate

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs ng-repeat i have to display distance between device to place using google map. I am sharing code what i have done but its not working but when i check it in breakpoint it get distance but do not update in the placeholder "{{ Show_Distance(place[3], place[4]) }}".

HTML Page:

```
<ons-row ng-repeat="place in PlacesList" style="border-bottom:solid 6px orange;">
<ons-col>
    <ons-button modifier="clean" ng-click="showPlacesDetails($index)">
        <img src="{{ place[1] }}">
        <div style="position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%;">
            {{ Show_Distance(place[3], place[4]) }}
        </div>
    </ons-button>
</ons-col>
```

In Controller js file:

```
$scope.Show_Distance = function (lat, lng) {
     var Distance = Get_Distance(lat, lng);
     return Distance;
};

function Get_Distance(lat, lng) {
        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var Distance = 'Distance: N.A.';
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [new google.maps.LatLng($rootScope.deviceLatitude, $rootScope.deviceLongitude)],
            destinations: [new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        },
        function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                Distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                //alert(Distance);
            }
        });
        return Distance;
    }
```

Help will be appriciated.

Edited:
PlacesList contsins(1 place):

```
<Value><string>1</string><string>Forresta Kitchen & Bar</string><string>Forresta Kitchen is nice place</string><string>26.920979</string><string>75.793934</string><string>4</string><string>images/PlacesMedia/1_01.jpg</string></Value>
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr so we can easily edit your code. Also please share your PlacesList Json

Comment: `getDistanceMatrix` is asynchronous and will update the primitive after it is returned from your function. Primitives don't have inheritance, use an object instead or return a promise from function

Comment: @charlietfl ...thanks 4 reply and can u show me any example of promise function for this situation actually i am new to angularjs and couldn't find any suitable example from google.

Comment: see the angular $q docs

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get distance between longitude and latitude which doesn't make any sense, you have to use two point each one have it's own longitude and latitude and then calculate the distance here's a practical example : 
x:longitude y:latitude
[image]